# How do you use a parameter to a function that errors in the error handling code?

Tags: rust

```
fn test() {
    use std::path::PathBuf;
    use std::fs::File;

    let filename: PathBuf = PathBuf::from("hello");
    let filename_clone = filename.clone();
    match File::open(filename) {
        Ok(_fp) => {
            unimplemented!();
        }
        Err(_error) => {
            println!("{}", filename_clone.display()); // Works
            println!("{}", filename.display()); // Fails
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `filename`
  --> src/lib.rs:13:28
   |
5  |     let filename: PathBuf = PathBuf::from("hello");
   |         -------- move occurs because `filename` has type `std::path::PathBuf`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
6  |     let filename_clone = filename.clone();
7  |     match File::open(filename) {
   |                      -------- value moved here
...
13 |             println!("{}", filename.display()); // Fails
   |                            ^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3c0d7d56774fe573c673034ca4866504)</sup>

We understand that using `filename` fails because `File::open` has borrowed it and not yet released it. Yet, in the case where the `open` fails (due to, say, the file not existing) we want to report on the actual input given to the `open`. We can get around this by cloning the filename before we open it - but in that case we are essentially doubling the memory in the expectation but not the certainty that an error arises. This seems wrong-headed.

What is the correct way to handle this case? How do you bubble up information from the point of failure that makes for expressive and precise error handling? Or am I misunderstanding something about the mechanism here that would make it clear?

Comment: @JohnKugelman isn’t that `todo!()` masking the error (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3c0d7d56774fe573c673034ca4866504)?. (Also https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/69834).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the call `File::open(filename)`, `filename` hasn’t been borrowed, but rather *moved* and so you can’t use it later.

`File::open` accepts any `AsRef<Path>`, and so you can pass a reference to your `PathBuf` (note the `&`):

```
File::open(&filename)
```

Now it has been borrowed, and you can use it later in the error handling code.

Comment: This makes so much more sense now! Thank you; John K's comment had me trying to figure out how my minimal case was so different, but I see that was a slight herring. I admit I'm a little unclear on the moving vs borrowed (obviously), but hopefully I can find some good guidance on that on the internet. The by-ref option is clearly what I was looking for here!